# Javascript call in eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery

This must be some misunderstanding on my part about something basic and I know javascript call had been explained many times over. But I cant get my head over this issue.
I have the following button in a page -

```
<button id="test" class="clickClass">Click Me</button>
```

Why the following event-handler gets executed immediately on page load?

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
//Shows on document load
$('.clickClass').on('click',testClick.call(this))
})
```

However, if I wrap the .call inside another function it gets executed as expected (only when I click the button) -

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
//Shows only when the button is clicked
$('.clickClass').on('click',function(){testClick.call(this)})
})
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Please let me know if I need to put some more explanation about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `call()` invokes the function immediately and assigns the result to the `click` handler.

Instead you should just provide the function by reference, then `this` will be the clicked element by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickClass').on('click', testClick)
})

function testClick() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickClass" id="foo">Click me</div>
```

Comment: I tried this with bind as well. But if I use bind(this) then the function receives document object passed to it (through "this"). How do I make sure that does not happen with bind?

Comment: That was a mistake - I misread your question. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if I want to pass parameter to testClick? The reference approach wont work in that case..right?

Comment: Yep, in that case you'd need to wrap your function call as in your second code block - but you don't need to use `call()` at all

Comment: Got it and thanks for the explanation. I knew call is not needed, however I tried to experiment with it to see if I can find a way around without another function wrapper. Looks like its not possible.